# htaccess subfolders for html site

Tags: .htaccess

My htaccess code is not working correctly.  Hoping to get some help.  It's working perfectly unless I click a link within on of my subfolder pages.  Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I removed the .html and added a trailing slash.

When I click on a link when I am within one of my subfolder pages, it generates a weird URL.

Example: When I am at the URL: http://domainname.com/product/2-jars-500mg-hemp-extract-pain-relief-cream/

and I click on the link: href = '/product/3-jars-500mg-full-spectrum-hemp-extract-pain-relief-cream'

It rewrites the link as /product/2-jars-500mg-hemp-extract-pain-relief-cream/3-jars-500mg-full-spectrum-hemp-extract-pain-relief-cream which causes a 404 error.

I currently online have one htaccess file in the public_html folder

This site is hosted through GoDaddy on an apache server.

I tried adding the same htaccess file into the product folder, but that messes up the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Rules looks fine, check in source code in browser your url... maybe it's relative and without slash at the beginning or end of uri ( example product/3-jars-500mg... not /product/3-jars-500mg.../ )

You need href = '/product/3-jars-500mg-full-spectrum-hemp-extract-pain-relief-cream/'
that the rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html` would be true.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped figure the issue out.  It seems to be that when writing these links within the products pages, I need to include the trailing slash for the links to generate correctly.  Not sure I quite understand why.